# Dictionary element reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working with dictionaries and the most problem that they are referenced to each other. I need to create a deep clone (smth like this it's named).

I use *population* as initial dictionary where I store graphs, then I need to take elements from *Population*, change them, write to *childPopulation*  then some calculations and changed elements becomes in *scores*. Finnaly I need to merge *population* and *scores* dictionaries.

The problem is that when I change elements from *population* they changed there ofcause. I need some how to create a copy of *population* whil will be not referenced with initial.

```
        population = new Dictionary<AdjacencyGraph<Figure, TaggedEdge<Figure, double>>, double>();
        addElement(p1, initialGraph);
        Run(initialGraph, p1);
        double scoreBest = RMSECalc();
        population.Add(initialGraph, scoreBest);
        while (scoreBest >= 1.0)
        {
            childPopulation = new List<AdjacencyGraph<Figure, TaggedEdge<Figure, double>>>();
            var parentList = new Dictionary<AdjacencyGraph<Figure, TaggedEdge<Figure, double>>, double>();

            foreach (var parent in population)
            {
                childPopulation.Add(Mutate(parent.Key));
            }
            GetBestSolution(childPopulation);
            scores = scores.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            if (scores.First().Value < scoreBest)
                scoreBest = scores.First().Value;
            scores.ToList().ForEach(x => population.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
            population.Take(50);
            scores = new Dictionary<AdjacencyGraph<Figure, TaggedEdge<Figure, double>>, double>();
            childPopulation = new List<AdjacencyGraph<Figure, TaggedEdge<Figure, double>>>();
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using structs instead of reference types?

Comment: One option for doing deep clones is to do a binary serialization and deserialization.  Otherwise you have to write your own code for doing the cloning.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use serialization cause Adjacency graph is not mention as serializable. And I also can not fix the source code. Same as I can not use interface IClonable